# Free a overwritten pointer

Tags: c, pointers, free, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have this problem:

```
char** words = (char**)calloc(10, sizeof(char*));
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    words[i] = (char*)calloc(100, sizeof(char));
}
```

I create a array of strings this way. Than in code I overwrite pointers (words[i])

```
char* str = calloc(strlen(temp), sizeof(char));
//fill str
words[index] = str;
```

And when I try to free the memory, I get HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED error.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    free(words[i]);
}
free(words);
```

Is there any way how to do it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [Please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917).

Comment: `free` has no idea where you stored the original pointer returned by `malloc`, or that you overwrote it. It only cares that you give it a pointer value that `malloc` gave in the first place.

Comment: `char* str = calloc(strlen(temp), sizeof(char));` --> `char* str = calloc(strlen(temp)+1, sizeof(char));`

Comment: You must free the original value in `words[index]`

Answer (score 0):

You are lucky to have got an error! Free-ing unallocated memory is just Undefined Behaviour, so it could work during all your tests and only break when you put code in production...

The rule is **NEVER erase a malloc-ed pointer before it has been freed**. You may have very good reasons to overwrite the `words` array (I do not know everything in your code) but in that case you could either use two different arrays:

- one that you *malloc* and keep until you free it
- one that you initially load from the former, proceed as you need and do not use it for freeing anything.

As a common alternative, you should free the allocated memory before reusing the pointer:

```
char* str = calloc(strlen(temp), sizeof(char));
//fill str
free(words[index]); // avoid the memory leak
words[index] = str; // correct because str points to another allocated buffer
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! Now I know I have an error in code.

```
char* str = calloc(strlen(temp)+1, sizeof(char));
```

This actually solved the HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED error, but I will repair the code according to your advices.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite easy actually.
You just need to do this:

```
char** words = (char**)calloc(10, sizeof(char*));
```

And the to copy the string to a heap address:

```
words[i]=strdup(temp);
```

Simple as this.

`strdup` is a function from `<string.h>` that is this:

```
char* strdup(char* s)
{
    char* ret=malloc(strlen(s)+1);
    strcpy(ret,s);
    return ret;
}
```

It's pointless to allocate and then copy when you can just do it in 1 simple step.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, by saying

```
 words[index] = str;
```

you're overwriting the previously allocated pointer, thereby losing the actual pointer (returned by initial call to `calloc()`), causing memory leak. You should use `strcpy()` to copy the content, not the pointer itself.

Something like

```
 strcpy(words[index], str);
```

should do the job for you.

Having said that,

```
 char* str = calloc(strlen(temp) , sizeof(char));
```

also looks wrong. You are probably missing the space for null-terminator while *`//fill str`* part. You may need

```
char* str = calloc(strlen(temp)+ 1, 1);  //sizeof char == 1, guaranteed in C
```

Comment: This isn't the cause of the heap corruption, though.

Comment: @AndrewMedico Please en-light me. :)